# Sharepoint Master page Css issue

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a master page in Sharepoint 2013 when i preview that in browser I see this line added

```
<style type="text/css">
     .ui-dialog-titlebar,.ms-dlgTitle,#s4-ribbonrow
         {
            background-color:rgb(0, 113, 198)  ! important;    
         }
</style>
```

While as this is not added any where , because of this my title of all pop up are coming blue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple way to apply the desired color by overriding the .ms-dlgTitle css at the page level.

Comment: But that will be difficult to maintain I am trying to understand reason why is this being added